# Synonym of "button" as a technological term?

Tags: synonyms

Do you know any appropriate synonyms for the word "button" in the context of User Interface design?

Comment: As far as I am aware of, there is no synonym that does not use "button" in it. (push button I have heard, but it uses button)

Comment: As someone who has worked with quite a few Grafical User Interface builders, I have to say, that all of them have acknowledged a button as a button. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: (1) In graphical user interfaces, a button is a small outlined area in a dialog box that you can click to select an option or command. (http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/B/button.html) You may like to try ux.stackexchange.com also. I do not think there's any other equivalent technical term.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is computer interface design terminology and should be asked on the appropriate SE site.

Answer (score 1):

Because the context is limited to User Interface design the word available is button, but you could of course use descriptive words. For example,

> "The main screen was occupied by *clickable boxes*."
>
> "The control board screen littered with *action boxes*."

The problem is the word *button* is extremely succinct within the user interface context. Any attempt at rewording can only be done through the use of secondarily descriptive words.

Comment: clickable boxes are not necessarily buttons - e.g. check boxes

Answer (score 0):

In some circumstances, [icon](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/icon) will work:

> A picture on a screen that represents a specific file, directory, window, option, or program.